# Update MySQL Field from OSCommerce Cookie

Tags: php, mysql, oscommerce

Hi, I need to update the database. I made this code but it's not working:

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['credits_id'])) {
tep_db_query("update " . TABLE_CUSTOMERS . " set credits+ WHERE customers_id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['credits_id']). "'");
}
else
{
echo 'fout';
}
?>

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+ WHERE customers_id='17'' at line 1

update customers set credits+ WHERE customers_id='17'

[TEP STOP]
```

---

It needs to update the field `credits` in table `customers`.  How can I do this?

Comment: Using this type of "authentication", everybody can increase all credits. Are you sure you want that?

Answer (score 1):

Your update query is not proper:

```
"update " . TABLE_CUSTOMERS . " set credits = credits + $someNewValue WHERE customers_id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['credits_id']). "'"
```

Hope it helps